# Is there a way to quantify the chirality of a 3d shape?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

A propeller is a chiral structure. Propellers can have low or large pitch. Pitch differences can be seen as distinguishing propellers with low chirality from those with large chirality.

Is there a general way, given a closed 3d shape, to quantify its chirality? Is there some sort of integral over the shape that yields a number quantifying the degree of chirality of that shape?

Comment: You asked the same question in math.stackexchange.com. At least provide a link to the  other question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a topic of some research, summarized in [On quantifying chirality — Obstacles and problems towards unification](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01277559). One metric is the Hausdorff chirality, which quantifies the chirality of a geometric representation of an object by measuring the degree of coincidence of the object with its mirror image, see [The Hausdorff chirality measure and a proposed Hausdorff structure measure.](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Hausdorff-chirality-measure-and-a-proposed-Yewande-Neal/0a7f7b2433ff23383fbf247e8a50381b0c8efae5)

Comment: But the Hausdorff method, as the first paper says, only works for discrete and finite sets of points. It does not work for shapes, which are continuous and infinite sets of points. Is there some method for shapes?

Comment: Certainly, you would need to fit a discrete pattern onto your shape. I doubt that any computationally efficient method would work without a discretization.